# 1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)' when saving

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to save some items to mysql with python and keep getting this error

I have connected to the db and then do a query on table1 and then later am trying to save to Resturants like this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `table1`")
#do some stuff
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Resturants (School,Resturant_Name,Phone,Street,City, State,Postal_Code,Country,Lat,Lng, Rating,Review_Count,Mobile_Url,Url) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s)", (SCHOOL,bus_name,bus_phone,bus_address,bus_city, bus_state,bus_post,bus_country,bus_lat,bus_lng, bus_rating,bus_rating_count,bus_mobile_url,bus_url))
```

here is error

```
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

And then I get the error on the `INSERT` line why?

Comment: so surrond name with ``? and its a capital "Name" does that matter? and I'm not sure what you mean with the second comment

Comment: @bernie I changed it to `VALUES` still same error, I also change `Name` to `Test_Name` and still getting error

Comment: [MySQL accepts either](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html), @Bernie.

Comment: @bernie is there anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: @BK435 I tried that but it does get to the print statement because it fails first also see full INSERT statemtent above, but I can't see anythign wrong with it?

Comment: Before you run the query, print out each of the variables `(SCHOOL,bus_name,bus_phone,bus_address,bus_city, bus_state,bus_post,bus_country,bus_lat,bus_lng, bus_rating,bus_rating_count,bus_mobile_url,bus_url)` and post the result here